# Record Triggered flow getting triggered whenever any field of Opportunity object is updated

Tags: visual-workflow

I created a flow where in when opportunity amount record is updated greater then 10000 , an email should go to opportunity owner. The error i am facing is when some other field is updated , still the mail is going to opportunity owner. What changes should i do in my flow such that only when amount is updated, only then the mail should go to user.
In the Flow ->
Configure trigger : When record is created or Updated
Set Entry condition : Amount Greater than 10000 AND AccountId IsNull False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  this Flow , you  have given the Entry conditions and would have made it After Save as it has to send the Email . So for every and on any field change in the Opportunity , it is meeting the Entry Conditions and Triggering the flow . Which is why you are getting the mail on every change.

So instead of setting the Entry conditions , change it to Formula evaluates to true .

In the Formula Field use this formula :

```
OR( AND(ISNEW(), {!$Record.Amount} >10000, NOT(ISNULL({!$Record.AccountId}))),
 AND( ISCHANGED({!$Record.Amount}),{!$Record.Amount} >10000, NOT(ISNULL({!$Record.AccountId}) )))
```

This will work .

Answer (score 1):

In your flow, navigate to the Configure Start conditions node.

There is a section below the "Set Entry Conditions" with a header "**When to Run the Flow for Updated Records**". Ensure the second option is selected, "Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements".

That selection will ensure that flow only runs when the start condition criteria is met ONLY when the record was updating to meet the start condition criteria.

[image: When to Run Flow for Updated Records]